# How do I verify two consecutive calls to a mock service in my JUnit test with mockito?

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, verify

I'm using Spring 4.3.8.RELEASE, JUnit 4.12 ,and Mockito 1.10.18.  I'm trying to test whether my "publishEvent" method is called from below ...

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class MyObjectServiceImpl implements MyObjectService, ApplicationEventPublisherAware
{

    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationEventPublisher(ApplicationEventPublisher publisher) 
    {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }
    ...
    public void myMethod(MyObject obj) {
    ...
            publisher.publishEvent(new ThirdPartyUpdateUserEvent(userId));
            publisher.publishEvent(new ThirdPartyUpdateObjectEvent(objectId));
```

and then in my JUnit test I have

```
@Before
public final void setup()
{
    eventPublisher = Mockito.mock(ApplicationEventPublisher.class);
    ((ApplicationEventPublisherAware) myObjectService).setApplicationEventPublisher(eventPublisher);
    ((ApplicationEventPublisherAware) userService).setApplicationEventPublisher(eventPublisher);
}   // setup

@Test
...
       // Verify first call
    final ArgumentCaptor<ThirdPartyUpdateUserEvent> argument2 = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ThirdPartyUpdateUserEvent.class);
    Mockito.verify(eventPublisher, Mockito.times(2)).publishEvent(argument2.capture());
    Assert.assertEquals("Failed to call method with proper argument.", userId, argument2.getValue().getUserId());
    // Verify second call
    final ArgumentCaptor<ThirdPartyUpdateMyObjectEvent> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ThirdPartyUpdateMyObjectEvent.class);
    Mockito.verify(eventPublisher, Mockito.times(2)).publishEvent(argument.capture());
    Assert.assertEquals("Failed to call method with proper argument.", objectId, argument.getValue().getObjectId());
```

Through debugging, I can see that each of the "publishEvent" methods is called exactly once, yet when I go to verify the calls I get the error for the first "verify" line in my @Test

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mainco.subco.ThirdPartyItem.domain.ThirdPartyUpdateMyObjectEvent cannot be cast to org.mainco.subco.ThirdPartyItem.domain.ThirdPartyUpdateUserEvent
    at com.follett.fdr.lycea.lms.MyObject.test.service.MyObjectServiceDWRTest.testArchiveMyObject(MyObjectServiceDWRTest.java:1234)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

What's the right way to verify two consecutive calls to my mocked publish service?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an ArgumentCaptor for ThirdPartyUpdateUserEvent and 
ThirdPartyUpdateMyObjectEvent, why not create one captor for Object:

```
final ArgumentCaptor<Object> argumentsCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Object.class);
```

Or better yet, whatever common interface ThirdPartyUpdateUserEvent and ThirdPartyUpdateMyObjectEvent implement (ThirdPartyUpdateEvent?)

Now you can do this:

```
Mockito.verify(eventPublisher, Mockito.times(2)).publishEvent(argumentsCaptor.capture());
List<Object> arguments = argumentsCaptor.getAllValues();
assertTrue(arguments.get(0) instanceof ThirdPartyUpdateUserEvent);
assertTrue(arguments.get(1) instanceof ThirdPartyUpdateMyObjectEvent);
```

And test those arguments for whatever other conditions you need.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem though, right?  By asserting that "arguements.get(1) instanceof ThirdPartyUpdateMyObjectEvent", all you're doing is verifyihng the class of the argumnet, but you're ignoring the ID.  I still want to verify the ID, otherwise many different objects of that class would satisfy the assertion even if they are the wrong ones.

Comment: @Dave after checking object type with instanceof you can safely cast it to right type and verify ID